# ¿Cómo abrir enlace automáticamente después de cierto tiempo?

Tags: jquery

Estoy usando una función de jQuery, que permite abrir un enlace automáticamente:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#some')[0].click();
    });
</script>
<a id="some" href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/">Automatico</a>
```

Me pueden explicar como hacer para que esta función se ejecute pero después de pasado `x` segundos o minutos.

Comment: si dices que automáticamente entonces no deberías ocupar un evento que lo dispare como el click

Comment: @alfap Entonces mi amigo como sería... Yo busque y en los ejemplos que lo ejecute automático así estaban.

Comment: @alfap Ah! ya se a que se refiere, pero en la segunda opción, es para ir directamente aún sitio, mi idea es poder ejecutar algún enlace en especifico mediante un id o clase, pero ya esta muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('#some')[0].click();
},3000);//tiempo de espera en milisegundos.
```

Con `setTimeout` se ejecutará luego de 3 segundos en este caso. 1000 milisegundos es igual a 1 minuto.

Extra:

Si no necesitas el enlace puedes redireccionar la pagina sin tener que agregar una etiqueta `<a>`, de esta forma:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
      window.location.href = "https://es.stackoverflow.com";
    },3000);
```

Comment: esta me parece la respuesta mas acertada a la situación expuesta con la segunda opción

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez Gracias por proporcionarme dos alternativas y sobre todo por la explicación :)

Comment: Me alegra haber ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que utilizar `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#some')[0].click();
}, 2000);
```